# Is it helpful to wrap `System.in` of type `BufferedInputStream` into a `BufferedReader`?

Tags: java, io

I found that the default type of `System.in` is `BufferedInputStream`, by

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

and I saw a lot of uses of `System.in` by wrapping it into a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Are `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedReader` redundant with each other?

Is it helpful to wrap `System.in` into a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: To answer your second question: yes and no. It's not beneficial to buffer user input from the console, but it is more likely to be useful when redirecting `System.in` to another `InputStream`, such as one from a file.

Comment: “I found that the default type of System.in is BufferedInputStream” You mean it *happens to be implemented* as a BufferedInputStream.  But the field is of type InputStream, so a later release is perfectly within its rights to change System.in to a different implementation of InputStream in the future.  One should not assume it has buffering.  So, wrapping it in a BufferedReader is entirely appropriate.